# How to automate Desktop application using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

One of project requirement is to automate Desktop application and client suggested to use robot framework. Is there any Library to automate desktop application as i am new to RF.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Have you checked the RobotFramewor.org site, have you searched in Google, have you experimented and are facing a technical issue? Please update your question with these kinds of details.[ask]

Answer (score 0):

Please go through "OperatingSystem Library" "SSHLibrary" "processLibrary"  in robot framework, you will get some idea